# amavis consider catchall as unknown

Tags: linux, sendmail, spamassassin, amavis

I'm running sendmail with amavis + amavis-milter on SERVER "A". SERVER "B" is working behind SERVER "A" which holds multiple domains. Some of the domains having catchall accounts for unknown users.

Emails for unknown users are being considered as unknown user by SERVER "A".

Comment: anyone please reply...

Comment: I find the question difficult to understand. What it being asked? Is server A a relay in front of server B? Is the opposite happening? How are the catchall addresses defined? What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark, because your question is not detailed much.

So my Interpretion of your problem:

You are using Server "A" just as a Mailrelay for Domains on Server "B".
In that case Server "A" does not need to know anything about users in a domain which Server "B" is responsible for.

Use on Server "A" in your .mc:

```
FEATURE(mailertable, `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable')
```

Then build your sendmail.cf with m4.

After doing so, setup your mailertable on Server "A":

```
example.com                   esmtp:[SERVER "B"]
```

Then the well known:

```
makemap hash mailertable < mailertable
```

Im running nearly the same setup and all is working fine.